# How can I add a class in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with Enom API and this API uses its own Interface (not Codeigniters) as shown below:

```
<?php
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/class.EnomInterface.php' );

Class EnomService extends EnomInterface{

function checkDomain($sld, $tld, $spinner = false, $allowDash = true, $word1 = '', $word2 = '', $word3 = ''){
$this->_setCommand('Check');

$this->addParam('SLD', $sld);
if( strstr($tld, ',') )
{
  $this->addParam('TLDList', $tld);
}
else
{
  $this->addParam('TLD', $tld);
}

if( $spinner && !strstr($tld, ',') )
{
    $this->addParam('DomainSpinner', '1');
    $this->addParam('AllowDash', $allowDash ? '1' : '0');
    if('' != $word1)
        $this->addParam('Word1', $word1);
    if('' != $word2)
        $this->addParam('Word2', $word2);
    if('' != $word3)
        $this->addParam('Word3', $word3);
}

if( !$this->process() || '0' != $this->response['ErrCount'] )
{
  return $this->_returnError();
}

$result = array();

if($spinner)
{
    $i = 1;
    while( isset($this->response['SuggestedName' . $i]) )
    {
        $result[$this->response['SuggestedName' . $i]] = true;
        $i++;
    }
}

if( !isset($this->response['DomainCount']) || '1' == $this->response['DomainCount'] )
{
  $result["$sld.$tld"] = ('210' == $this->response['RRPCode']) ? true : false;
  return $result;
}

for($i=1; $i<=$this->response['DomainCount']; $i++)
{
  $result[ $this->response[('Domain'.$i)] ] = ('210' == $this->response[('RRPCode'.$i)]) ? true : false;
}

return $result;
}
}
```

This has more functions but I guess you guys get the point.

Anyway, I am trying to load it like this:

```
$this->load->library('Enom/class.EnomService');
```

And the classes are in:

```
libraries/Enom/class.EnomService.php
libraries/Enom/class.EnomInterface.php
```

What it tells me it has an internal server error.

Could somebody please help me with this implementation?

PS: I am new to Codeigniter.. :)

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

As a conclusion, ENOM and other API's use many Interfaces and variables between them wich may cause conflict with the loader class of the codeigniter.

I managed to solve this issue was not implementing it through the loader class but directly through the require and include variables.

It turned out something like this:

```
require_once('application/libraries/enom/class.EnomService.php');
$enom = new EnomService($registrar_username, $registrar_password, false, true);
$enom->debug = true;
```

Instead of:

```
$this->load->library('Enom/class.EnomService');
```

If anyone needs any further explenation I would me more than glad to help.

Thanks to everyone who helped on the way, Specially Phill.

Comment: What's the `$this` object, that has a `load` property on which you call `library()`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. It is actually being called from a model extending CI_Model. Where I suppose it is comming from there. More importantly, I have checked the documentation and the implementation method is explained here and it still doesnt work "http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html". Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

Just include the class file, like EnomService does to get the EnomInterface, and you should be able to use `EnomService` as [Enom documents](http://www.phpkode.com/source/s/enom-api/enom-api/example.checkDomain.php).

```
include APPPATH.'libraries/Enom/class.EnomService.php';

$enom = new EnomService('username', '********', false, true);
$enom->debug = true;

$result = $enom->checkDomain('systurn', 'com', true);

var_dump($result);
```

---

[`APPPATH`](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/189755/) refers to the `application` directory in CodeIgniter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I did was change this code:

    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/class.EnomInterface.php' );

for this one:

    include APPPATH.'libraries/Enom/class.EnomService.php';

and it shows me this error:

    Unable to load the requested class: class.enomservice

I also sense that you cannot implement a method that is not codeigniters or so it says in the documentation, but how could it be implemented then?

Comment: Once you have included your file you should be able to use `new EnomService('username', '********', false, true)` (not `class.enomservice`).  Perhaps you can point us to the documentation for the library?

Comment: I've just re-read what you commented - you should not need to change anything in the class.EnomService.php file!  Use my example where you want to use the EnomService.

Comment: I have made many changes and still no luck. For example change the names from class.EnomService to enomservice etc. It fixes some stuff but damages other stuff. I will keep looking for the solutions and keep you guys updates. Thanks.

Comment: Please update your question with the current code that you are trying to use, especially the code loading the service.  Please remember that use of upper and lower case is very important and must be consistent.